# excel vba to run a different macro for each value in the filter

Tags: vba, excel

I have 4 different macros. I need to know if there is a way to run one macro on a master sheet, where if column D has 16 values and only 4 are unique values, it should cycle through those 4 values and run a macro associated to that value. Need to fix this asap!

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
Sub sistence()
    Dim rD As Range
    Set rD = Range("D1:D100")
    For Each r In rD
        v = r.Value
        If v = "A" Then Call MacroA
        If v = "B" Then Call MacroB
        If v = "C" Then Call MacroC
        If v = "D" Then Call MacroD
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: The thing is, the data is like this

`Column D
A
A
A
B
C
D
D
A
C
C`

I want to filter out A and run MacroA, then filter out B and run Macro B and then C and Macro C with that, etc

Comment: When you say filter out A, do you mean hide the rows with A in them?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. Filter **Only** A and run MacroA etc. Also, the other Macros, create a new workbook each time it is run. When I run MacroA for A using the above code, it runs fine, but then when it moves to B, the MacroB takes the newly created workbook by MacroA as the masterfile. this should not happen. it should run the macro on the first Master File. Hopefully I make sense :(

Comment: And I dont want this to be recursive. I want this to run the other Macro's once for each value.